# Resize control to match aspect ratio

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, aspect-ratio

**Description**

I am creating a "simulator" for different resolutions. Basically I have a control inside a panel. Then the user can choose an aspect ratio (more information below) and the control inside the simulator should get resized to match the desired ratio.

**Problem**

The problem is that I do not know what is a good way to calculate the size of the control without having to use a lot of CPU or trying or resizing. How can I know, if I have to resize the height or the width of the control to fit inside the simulator?

The simulator can grow or shrink. That is why I can not be sure, if the control inside of it will fill up the whole width of the simulator, or the height, but the aspect ratio should be always correct.

**Hint**

This is probably a very easy mathematical problem. I just don't find a solution right now (today is not my day)!

If you have any ideas or suggestions, feel free to ask and propose!

**Example**

[image: Example for the simulator.]

**Available Resolutions**

- 3:2 (Like on the iPhone until iPhone 5; Anyone knows an other name?)
- 16:10 (WXGA)
- 16:9 (Widescreen)
- 4:3 (VGA)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you after `height = width / widthRatio * heightRatio`? (or in reverse)

Comment: Ok. But the control inside the simulator should fill up either width or height of the simulator. How do I know if I have to take the height of the control to the maximum or the width? I would have to try, I guess?

Comment: Im short of a better answer, sorry. There is always going to be some odd looking controls when you are trying to apply the same layout to a selection of resolutions

Comment: Yes. Maybe the control will look odd, but the simulator is exactly to simulate how it will look on each resolution. The main problem is that one of the sides is fix. Either the width of the control represents the width of the simulator, or the height of the control the one of the simulator. I do not know how to choose which one, without having to try it out each time the simulator changes size.

Comment: It is a case of trying it out, but I would think that you choose the element that has the larger ratio, width in this case, since this has less chance of detail getting cropped

Comment: @El Mac: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little testbed. Put a control on a form and assign the ViewPort variable to it. Here I chose a textBox1 but any control will do. Then pick a target aspect ratio, I chose TargetRatio_3_2.
Try it by resizing the form!

Note 1: I chose a form as the Container (your *Simulator*) for easier testing and therefore use its ClientRectangle to access its inner measures. Any other Control will basically work the same.

Not 2: I have added a few lines to place the ViewPort (your *Control*) in the center.

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control Container = this;
    Control ViewPort = textBox1;

    float ContainerRatio = 1f * Container.ClientRectangle.Width / Container.ClientRectangle.Height;

    const float TargetRatio_3_2 = 3f / 2f;
    const float TargetRatio_16_9 = 16f / 9f;
    const float TargetRatio_4_3 = 4f / 3f;
    const float TargetRatio_16_10 = 16f / 10f;
    //..

    float TargetRatio = TargetRatio_3_2;

    if (ContainerRatio < TargetRatio)
    {
        ViewPort.Width = Container.ClientRectangle.Width;
        ViewPort.Height = (int)(ViewPort.Width / TargetRatio);
        ViewPort.Top = (Container.ClientRectangle.Height - ViewPort.Height) / 2;
        ViewPort.Left = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewPort.Height = Container.ClientRectangle.Height;
        ViewPort.Width = (int)(ViewPort.Height * TargetRatio);
        ViewPort.Top = 0;
        ViewPort.Left = (Container.ClientRectangle.Width - ViewPort.Width) / 2;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is basically how I solved it. I will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for your support!